# xml frame pause flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So is it posibble to create outside source from swf file so i can control frame pause lenght(xml file or AS pacage), and edit it with notepad. I have this code for each of my frames in swf file it goes like this:

Code on my first frame goes like this:

```
//PAUSE

function playit(e:TimerEvent):void {
play();
}

var Tim:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);
Tim.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playit);

stop();
Tim.delay = 100; //Adjust Accordingly - 1000 Equals 1 Second
Tim.start();
```

And on the rest of the frames (10 more frames) goes like this:

```
//PAUSE


stop();
Tim.delay = 10000; //Adjust Accordingly - 1000 Equals 1 Second
Tim.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it, but your code is a bit messy. If you are actually trying to set how much frames should be played per second (as I can see the timer), you should check `frameRate` property. You can read specific number from a source file and then set it with ActionScript.
You won't need all those play/stop/timer things..

Hope that's the idea, otherwise I'm speechless..

p.s.
If you still need some other kind of solution - use nextFrame/prevFrame with that timer, don't play/stop it all the time..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple but require a bit of math. Instead of letting the movie play you need to use your own custom system based on gotoAndStop(). You calculate the right timing and then call gotoAndStop() at the right moment with a variable of int type increasing on each call.

Comment: You don't show us your maths, you don't answer the question. -1